# C++ error redefinition of function in spite of using #ifndef

Tags: c++, function, object, oop

I've tried several times to get rid of the error, one of which was to use #ifndef but it hasn't worked yet. Please help!

**vec3.h** file

```
    #ifndef VEC3_H
#define VEC3_H

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using std::sqrt;

class vec3 {
    public:
        vec3() : e{0,0,0} {}
        vec3(double e0, double e1, double e2) : e{e0, e1, e2} {}

        double x() const { return e[0]; }
        double y() const { return e[1]; }
        double z() const { return e[2]; }

        vec3 operator-() const { return vec3(-e[0], -e[1], -e[2]); }
        double operator[](int i) const { return e[i]; }
        double& operator[](int i) { return e[i]; }

        vec3& operator+=(const vec3 &v) {
            e[0] += v.e[0];
            e[1] += v.e[1];
            e[2] += v.e[2];
            return *this;
        }

        vec3& operator*=(const double t) {
            e[0] *= t;
            e[1] *= t;
            e[2] *= t;
            return *this;
        }

        vec3& operator/=(const double t) {
            return *this *= 1/t;
        }

        double length() const {
            return sqrt(length_squared());
        }

        double length_squared() const {
            return e[0]*e[0] + e[1]*e[1] + e[2]*e[2];
        }

    public:
        double e[3];
};

// Type aliases for vec3
using point3 = vec3;   // 3D point
using color = vec3;    // RGB color

#endif
  
  
    // vec3 Utility Functions

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const vec3 &v) {
    return out << v.e[0] << ' ' << v.e[1] << ' ' << v.e[2];
}

inline vec3 operator+(const vec3 &u, const vec3 &v) {
    return vec3(u.e[0] + v.e[0], u.e[1] + v.e[1], u.e[2] + v.e[2]);
}

inline vec3 operator-(const vec3 &u, const vec3 &v) {
    return vec3(u.e[0] - v.e[0], u.e[1] - v.e[1], u.e[2] - v.e[2]);
}

inline vec3 operator*(const vec3 &u, const vec3 &v) {
    return vec3(u.e[0] * v.e[0], u.e[1] * v.e[1], u.e[2] * v.e[2]);
}

inline vec3 operator*(double t, const vec3 &v) {
    return vec3(t*v.e[0], t*v.e[1], t*v.e[2]);
}

inline vec3 operator*(const vec3 &v, double t) {
    return t * v;
}

inline vec3 operator/(vec3 v, double t) {
    return (1/t) * v;
}

inline double dot(const vec3 &u, const vec3 &v) {
    return u.e[0] * v.e[0]
         + u.e[1] * v.e[1]
         + u.e[2] * v.e[2];
}

inline vec3 cross(const vec3 &u, const vec3 &v) {
    return vec3(u.e[1] * v.e[2] - u.e[2] * v.e[1],
                u.e[2] * v.e[0] - u.e[0] * v.e[2],
                u.e[0] * v.e[1] - u.e[1] * v.e[0]);
}

inline vec3 unit_vector(vec3 v) {
    return v / v.length();
}
```

main file, **chap_3.cpp**

```
    #include "color.h"
#include "ray.h"
#include "vec3.h"

#include <iostream>


color ray_color(const ray& r) {
    vec3 unit_direction = unit_vector(r.direction());
    auto t = 0.5*(unit_direction.y() + 1.0);
    return (1.0-t)*color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) + t*color(0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
}

int main() {

    // Image

    const auto aspect_ratio = 16.0 / 9.0;
    const int image_width = 400;
    const int image_height = static_cast<int>(image_width / aspect_ratio);

    // Camera

    auto viewport_height = 2.0;
    auto viewport_width = aspect_ratio * viewport_height;
    auto focal_length = 1.0;

    auto origin = point3(0, 0, 0);
    auto horizontal = vec3(viewport_width, 0, 0);
    auto vertical = vec3(0, viewport_height, 0);
    auto lower_left_corner = origin - horizontal/2 - vertical/2 - vec3(0, 0, focal_length);

    // Render

    std::cout << "P3\n" << image_width << " " << image_height << "\n255\n";

    for (int j = image_height-1; j >= 0; --j) {
        std::cerr << "\rScanlines remaining: " << j << ' ' << std::flush;
        for (int i = 0; i < image_width; ++i) {

            auto u = double(i) / (image_width-1);
            auto v = double(j) / (image_height-1);
            ray r(origin, lower_left_corner + u*horizontal + v*vertical - origin);
            color pixel_color = ray_color(r);

            write_color(std::cout, pixel_color);
        }
    }

    std::cerr << "\nDone.\n";
}
```

How can I solve **errors** like the following:

```
enter codevec3.h: In function 'vec3 operator+(const vec3&, const vec3&)':
vec3.h:65:17: error: redefinition of 'vec3 operator+(const vec3&, const vec3&)'
 inline vec3 operator+(const vec3 &u, const vec3 &v) {
             ^~~~~~~~
In file included from color.h:4:0,
             from chap_3.cpp:1:
vec3.h:65:17: note: 'vec3 operator+(const vec3&, const vec3&)' previously defined here
     inline vec3 operator+(const vec3 &u, const vec3 &v) {
                 ^~~~~~~~ here
```

I've tried several sources but to no avail, also I picked the code from a trusted source and have made only minor changes so I am not able to understand why the error is occuring.

Comment: The [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) needs to protect the *whole* header file, not just parts of it.

Comment: Those functions are outside your `#ifdef` guards. Great case for not using obsolete constructs like those, and code properly using `#pragma once`.

Comment: General rule of thumb: When you get problems like this, back up your code and start hacking pieces out of it. When the problem suddenly goes away, the mistake is likely in the part you just removed. Examine it more closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inline definitions are after the `#ifndef`/`#endif` surrounding the rest of the header file, meaning they will be picked up by every `#include`. You can either

1. Move the `#endif` to the very end of the header file, or
2. Use `#pragma once` instead of the include guards (not standard but most compilers support it).

Comment: Not also that `once` can also be fooled by a build environment with a sufficiently complicated directory structure. These days the `once` supporting compilers are pretty bright and you rarely see this. Real bummer when it happens, though.

Comment: @user4581301 True, but I think you're more likely to come across `#ifndef` naming collisions than issues with `#pragma once`.

Comment: To be honest, I come across compilers that don't support `once` more often than naming collisions or `once`-breaking build environments.